# How to upload and view pdf in nz-upload?

Tags: javascript, angular15, ng-zorro-antd

`Hi, i am trying to upload pdf file in 17 version of nz-zorro , but it is showing in red color and        view button is disabled , but for image type it works fine and image is viewed and in version 7 it works fine for pdf     file here is my code  :

This is my code picture card to accept multiple pictures . I should able to upload and view both image and pdf file . currently i can view only image. and for pdf i view icon is disabled`

```
<nz-upload  nzAction="{}" nzListType="picture-card" [(nzFileList)]="viewDocFile" [nzShowButton]="nzUploadBoxBtn"[nzShowUploadList]="showUploadList" [nzPreview]="handlePreview" 
[nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload"><span nz-icon nzType="plus"></span><div class="ant-upload-text">Upload</div></nz-upload>
```